# CSS and JS take time to load when entering the site in production

Tags: javascript, next.js

Basically, every time i load the page only loads the HTML, and doesn't work with CSS or JS.

This happens during the hydration period of next.js

So, I looked for ways to better deal with hydration, I even found components that solve this, but I would like not to install third-party components, for performance reasons.

Can i solve this with a simple solution?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhgTW.jpg

Comment: check if your are rerendering components in NextJS, the flow for component rendering is a bit different from reactjs. It might be helpful if you understand the SSG and SSR thereby rendering components accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.